# Display progress on one php page for a process running on another php page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, event-handling

I have a upload.php page where the users upload a file and the file is converted to a HTML file and stored on the server. The conversion is carried out via a shell_exec() command. To display a conversion progressbar for this, I parse the stderr and pass the progress value to the javascript function as:

```
echo "<script>progress(".$base.",".$prog_val.") </script>";
```

This calls the javascript function as:

```
       function progress(base, value) //assigns value and max to progress bar in html

     { 
document.getElementById('prog').value = value;
 document.getElementById('prog').max = base; document.getElementById('progress_indicator').innerHTML = Math.ceil(value)+"/"+base+" pages";
 }
```

To display the progress bar I have:

```
<progress id = "prog"> </progress> <div id = "progress_indicator"></div>
```

All these are on the same upload.php page. So, when the process is running, the progress gets updated successfully but the user is not able to use the page as the conversion executes on the same php page. I want to run the conversion php part on another php page in the background and echo the "progress(".$base.",".$prog_val.") " on my upload.php page. So, that the conversion runs in the background without holding back the upload.php page in that time. I feel this can be achieved via ajax or event handlers.

Could someone please let me know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

make jquery ajax in upload.php page with external page that have your operations and then assign the returned value of ajax into fixed div in upload.php page.